# Updating from Rails 2 to Rails 3 with JQuery AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I am moving a site from Rails 2 to Rails 3 and need to replace the following deprecated methods, with JQuery:

```
periodically_call_remote 
button_to_remote
```

**In the view, there is a button that when pressed executes a callback every 12 seconds:**

```
#index.html.erb (Rails 2.2.2)

<%= periodically_call_remote(:url => { :action => 'check' }, :frequency => '12', :update => 'log') %>

[...]

<div id="generate_test_btn"><%= button_to_remote "Generate Test Order", 
                        :url => { :action => "check", :should_generate => "YES" },
                        :update => "log" %>
</div>

[...]


#controller
def check

    [...Generate content...]

    render :partial => "log" and return

end
```

**My Partial Implementation**
Not sure how to glue **button_to** code to the JQuery AJAX stuff

```
 ### index.html.erb  (Rails 3.1)
   <script>


$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#generate_test_button").click(function() {

        setInterval(updateTest,12000);
      });

    });

  function updateTest(){
    $("#log").load("???"); 
  }

</script>


    <%= button_to "Generate Test Order", 
                  { :controller => :test, :action=> :check, :should_generate => "YES" }, 
                  { :remote => true } 
                 %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in rails 3 you have unobtrusive javascript

so basically, any link you create with `:remote => true` would call that `controller#action` but with a js.erb ending

so in your case the button would call the `check` action in the `test` controller

if you create a check.js.erb and place it in the `views/test` folder and have inside

```
alert("UJS!");
```

it should pop up once you press that button

also note that you should have the rails-ujs gem and require it in the application.js manifest

Comment: Thanks. That helps. So how does the remote data from test/check, which does: render :partial => "log" and return relate to this new js file (check.js.erb)

Comment: you can handle `.js.erb` as if it is `html.erb`. it is basically a view but in js. you can access in variables you used in the controller via erb `<%= %>`, erb goes first then JS. so you can do things like `$("#check-<%= @check.id %>")` and such